# Is Berkeley XMLDB container portable?

Tags: berkeley-db, berkeley-db-xml

I created a container(pvs.dbxml) using Berkeley XMLDB 2.5.16 and moved the container to another machine.

Below is the error I got while opening the container in new machine

***dbxml> openContainer pvs.dbxml

stdin:1: openContainer failed, Error: Invalid argument***

Is this error occured because the container was copied from another machine?

Answer (score 2):

The container itself is portable across machines and most languages.

- Are you using the same library version?
- If you're using environments and/or transactions, did you make sure you copied everything over?
- If you're using a newer version, did you perform the upgrade process?